# How can I resize a div by dragging it at the top?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to resize a div while dragging the portion between two div's.

On search I found [this](http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/Bek9L/1779/) but I don't know how make this horizontal instead of available vertical drag?

My divs look like,

```
<div id="widnow">
<div id="button">-</div>
    <div id="title_bar"><b>Console Log</b></div>
    <div id="box">${logs}</div>
</div>
```

I want the title bar to be draggable vertically.

I don't want to use any third party plugin's.

Comment: I would go with [jQuery UI Layout](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/), which has all the functionality you need (and much more).

Comment: I don't want to complicate stuff by adding plugins

Comment: Then please add that you can't use 3rd party plugins because [reason] in your question to help. FWIW, the "complicate stuff" argument does not sound quite right - but page size would be a real argument.

Comment: Hi,check this: http://jsfiddle.net/Bek9L/1870/ I altered the code to make the divs horizontaly, unfortunetly I do not have the time to make that nice "gohst div" to work properly.

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Bek9L/1871/

Comment: @Pavlo Pl post it as answer so that I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed your code: 
Also, here is a **[Fiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Bek9L/1871/)**
HTML:

```
<div id="sidebar">
  <span id="position"></span>
  sidebar
</div>
<div id="dragbar"></div>
<div id="main">main</div>
```

CSS:

```
body,html{width:100%;height:100%;padding:0;margin:0;}
#main{
  background-color: BurlyWood;
  float: left;
  height:100px;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;    
}
#sidebar{
  background-color: IndianRed;  
  width:100%;
  float: left;
  height:100px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

#dragbar{
  background-color:black;
  height:5px;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: row-resize;
}
#ghostbar{
  width:3px;
  background-color:#000;
  opacity:0.5;
  position:absolute;
  cursor: col-resize;
  z-index:999
}
```

JavaScript Code:

```
var i = 0;
var dragging = false;
$('#dragbar').mousedown(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  dragging = true;
  var main = $('#main');
  var dragbar = $("#dragbar");
  var ghostbar = $('<div>',
    {id:'ghostbar',
        css: {
          height: dragbar.outerHeight(),
          width: dragbar.outerWidth(),
          top: main.offset().top,
          bottom: main.offset().bottom
        }
   }).appendTo('body');

   $(document).mousemove(function(e){
     ghostbar.css("top",e.pageY+2);
   });
});

$(document).mouseup(function(e){
  if (dragging){
    $('#sidebar').css("height",e.pageY+2);
    $('#main').css("top",e.pageY+2);
    $('#ghostbar').remove();
    $(document).unbind('mousemove');
    dragging = false;
  }
});
```