# How to adjust div height by dragging whole bottom border line instead of bottom right corner in react?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, layout, border

I have one react component. I am able to adjust the height by adding `resize: vertical;
  overflow: auto;` in my css file. However, I only can adjust by dragging bottom right corner of the border. Is it possible to change it to whole bottom line? Or any other react api can achieve this?
This is an [example](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_resize) of how I adjust the height by dragging bottom right corner.

This is my component.

```
<div class='map'>
      <MyMapComponent
        handleChange={this.handleChange}
        handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
        date ={this.state.date}
        getMap={this.getMap}
        updateStatus = {this.state.updateStatus}
        filter={this.state.filter}
        filterList={this.state.filterList}
        inputProps={{
            classes: {
                input: classes.multilineColor
            }
        }}
      >
      {/*this.getMap()*/}

      </MyMapComponent>
         </div>
```

This is my css file.

```
.map{
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 20px; 
  width: 300px;
  resize: vertical;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22654695/how-can-i-resize-a-div-by-dragging-it-at-the-top

Comment: @Soothran, that is jquery example,do you have react example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I follow this horizontal resize panel [example](https://codepen.io/lopis/pen/XYgRKz) to create a vertical one.

This is my edited resize panel

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import './ResizablePanels.css';

class ResizablePanels extends React.Component {
  eventHandler = null

  constructor () {
    super()

    this.state = {
      isDragging: false,
      panels: [800, 300, 0]
    }
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).addEventListener('mousemove', this.resizePanel)
    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).addEventListener('mouseup', this.stopResize)
    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).addEventListener('mouseleave', this.stopResize)
  }

  startResize = (event, index) => {
    this.setState({
      isDragging: true,
      currentPanel: index,
      initialPos: event.clientY
    })
  }

  stopResize = () => {
    if (this.state.isDragging) {
      console.log(this.state)
      this.setState(({panels, currentPanel, delta}) => ({
        isDragging: false,
        panels: {
          ...panels,
          [currentPanel]: (panels[currentPanel] || 0) - delta,
          [currentPanel - 1]: (panels[currentPanel - 1] || 0) + delta
        },
        delta: 0,
        currentPanel: null
      }))
      console.log(this.state)
    }
  }

  resizePanel = (event) => {
    if (this.state.isDragging) {
      //console.log(event.clientY +" "+this.state.initialPos);
      const delta = event.clientY - this.state.initialPos
      this.setState({
        delta: delta
      })
    }
  }

  render() {
    const rest = this.props.children.slice(1);
   // console.log(this.props);
    return (
      <div className="panel-container" onMouseUp={() => this.stopResize()}>
        <div className="panel" style={{height: this.state.panels[0]}}>
          {this.props.children[0]}
        </div>
        {[].concat(...rest.map((child, i) => {
          return [
            <div onMouseDown={(e) => this.startResize(e, i + 1)}
              key={"resizer_" + i}
              style={this.state.currentPanel === i+1 ? {top: this.state.delta} : {}}
              className="resizer"></div>,
            <div key={"panel_" + i} className="panel" style={{height: this.state.panels[i + 1]}}>
              {child}
            </div>
          ]
        }))}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default ResizablePanels;
```

and this is my css file for this panel

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu');

html {
  background: #333;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
h1 {
  color: white;
}

.panel-container {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
}

.panel {
  background: #EEE;
  border: 0px solid gray;
  padding: 1px;
}
.panel:first-child {

}

.resizer {
  height: 8px;
  background: darkGray;
  position: relative;
  cursor: row-resize;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  -webkit-user-select: none;  /* Chrome all / Safari all */
  -moz-user-select: none;     /* Firefox all */
  -ms-user-select: none;      /* IE 10+ */
  user-select: none;          /* Likely future */ 
}

.resizer::after,
.resizer::before {
  content: "";
  border-left: 1px solid #333;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  right: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0 2px;
}
.resizer::before {
  top: 0;
}
```